# Subtracting an int from a long long int

Tags: c++, casting, integer, long-integer

1. Can I subtract an `int` variable from a `long long int` variable?
2. In case I can't: I need to store a bigger number than a number that can stored in a `int`, and I don't want to use a `double` or `float` because I need integers, what can I do? I don't want to use all `long long int`. Is there a way to cast the `int` into a `long long int` so that I can make the subtraction?

Comment: Surely writing `int main() { long long int x = 100012u1928109111211LL; int y = 1234; printf("%lld\n", x - y); return 0; }` and `gcc -Wall -std=c99 mytest.c -o mytest` is shorter than this question?

Comment: @MatsPetersson - sure, it's shorter, but it won't compile. <g>

Comment: You mean it's missing #include <stdio.h> - it would still be shorter...

Comment: @MatsPetersson - no, sorry, meant to add an appendix: there's a stray `'u'` in the first constant.

Comment: Oh, that's what you get from typing fast... <grin>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can. The `int` will be converted by the *usual arithmetic conversions* to a `long long int` for the sake of the subtraction, so that both operands have the same integer conversion rank, and the result will also be a `long long int`.

This is covered by §5/9:

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result. This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*, which are defined as follows:
>
> [...]
>   if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned integer types, the
>   operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank shall be converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
>   [...]

The rank of `long long int` is greater than the rank of `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can subtract an `int` from a `long long int`. You won't need any explicit casts since the `int` will be widened automatically.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes; the result is a `long long` (until you cast it to something else; in fact, it is a `long long` but you might convert the result to a different type).
2. N/A.